JavaFX: Buttons NullPointerException When ComboBox is Populated
I'm working on a JavaFX application for a school project, and I've encountered a frustrating issue. The ComboBox in my MainController initializes correctly, but clicking on any of the buttons in the interface throws a NullPointerException only when I populate the ComboBox in the initialize method. If I remove the population of the ComboBox, everything works fine.
Code Snippets:
Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private StackPane mainPane;
    @FXML
    public VBox sidePanel;
    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> accessComboBox;

    private Employee employee;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // This line causes the buttons to throw errors
        accessComboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Employee", "Admin"));
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    private void loadScene(String fxmlPath) {
        try {
            SystemLogger.log(Level.INFO,"Loading FXML from path: " + fxmlPath);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            mainPane.getChildren().clear();
            mainPane.getChildren().setAll(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            SystemLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to load FXML from path: " + fxmlPath);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadHomeScene() {
        SystemLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Home button clicked.");
        loadScene("/view/employee/HomeScene.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadProfileScene() {
        SystemLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Profile button clicked.");
        loadScene("/view/employee/ProfileScene.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadAttendanceScene() {
        SystemLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Attendance button clicked.");
        loadScene("/view/employee/AttendanceScene.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadLeaveScene() {
        SystemLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Leave button clicked.");
        loadScene("/view/employee/LeaveScene.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadPayslipScene() {
        SystemLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Payslip button clicked.");
        loadScene("/view/employee/PayslipScene.fxml");
    }

    public void initComponents(Stage stage, Employee employee) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/Main.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("MotorPH Payroll Management System");
            stage.show();

            MainController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setEmployee(employee);

        } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}


FXML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="800.0" minWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.motorph.controller.MainController">
   <left>
       <VBox id="side_nav" fx:id="sidePanel" alignment="CENTER" minHeight="800.0" minWidth="200.0" spacing="20.0" stylesheets="@../css/style.css">
         <ComboBox fx:id="accessComboBox" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Access Type" />
           <Button minWidth="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadHomeScene" text="Home" />
           <Button layoutX="86.0" layoutY="398.0" minWidth="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadProfileScene" text="Profile" />
           <Button layoutX="85.0" layoutY="410.0" minWidth="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadAttendanceScene" text="Attendance" />
           <Button layoutX="72.0" layoutY="423.0" minWidth="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadLeaveScene" text="Leave" />
           <Button layoutX="60.0" layoutY="443.0" minWidth="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadPayslipScene" text="Payslip">
              <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
              </VBox.margin>
           </Button>
       </VBox>
   </left>
   <center>
      <StackPane fx:id="mainPane" minHeight="800.0" minWidth="1000.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>


Error Messages:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)" because "this.accessComboBox" is null
    at com.motorph.controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:33)

Question:
What could be causing the accessComboBox to be null when I try to populate it in the initialize method, especially since I use the initComponents method to load the FXML file? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Things I Tried:

Verified that the onAction methods in the FXML are correctly linked to the methods in the MainController.

Ensured that the FXML paths in the loadScene method are correct and that the corresponding FXML files exist.

Cleared the mainPane before loading new content.

Added logging to trace when buttons are clicked and when scenes are loaded.

Checked for null pointers, especially for mainPane, which could indicate it wasn't properly injected.



Why are you loading the FXML file in class MainController? I always load the FXML file from the start method of the class that extends javafx.application.Application, i.e. my JavaFX application class.

you need to show the full code or it will be impossible to tell you what you have wrong but im almost sure you are creating an instance of MainController by hand and using while having the correct one inside the initComponents method

The code in public void initComponents(Stage stage, Employee employee) seems suspect to me. What's going on there?

As well as a [mre], you should post the complete stack trace in the question (not just the first couple of lines).

Since you say that the error happens AFTER you click on a Button, and it indicates an error in MainController, my guess is that you are using the same Controller for all of your FXML layouts, which would be MainController.  And those other FXML files, that you haven't shown, do not define accessComboBox - so it's null when the initialize is run.

@DaveB Thank you. Yes, I have multiple FXML files that initially refer to the MainController. Creating separate controller for each FXML file solved the issue.
